# Rails: Better syntax for respond_to (shorthand)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code for the `update` method of a user settings controller:

```
def update
  @user = ...
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:success] = 'Some success message.'
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to some_path }
      format.js   { head :ok }
    end
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Some error message.'
    render action: 'some action'
  end
end
```

I'm wondering if there a way to shorten this whole method? Best option would be to reduce the number of lines for the `respond_to` block, if there's a way to use some shorthand syntax in there.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not supporting a js submission you can remove the respond_to block completely.  Also, note the use of `flash.now` which is needed to display a flash message on a render.

```
def update
  @user = ...
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:success] = 'Some success message.'
    redirect_to some_path
  else
    flash.now[:error] = 'Some error message.'
    render action: 'some action'
  end
end
```

Comment: Actually, I'm planning to have JS form submission, so even if I remove it now, I'll eventually have to add it back and will face the same problem.

Comment: Well, it's not a "problem", per se.  The original code's not excessive and seems reasonable.  Cheers.